# Long story about recycling an unwanted gift

Tags: story-identification

There's this really long book I read about eighteen years ago, though I'm fairly sure it's older than that. It starts with a guy receiving from his uncle a piece of jewelry he doesn't really want, and would like to get rid of. Only, this piece of jewelry has a really bad recycling policy - one has to physically bring the thing back to where it was manufactured, so it can be safely disposed of. Poor guy has to amass a party of all the standard fantasy races just to throw an unwanted birthday present into the appropriate recycling bin.

Comment: I think I've read that. Was there a dwarf-tossing subplot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's intended [as a joke](https://blazepress.com/.image/t_share/MTM3NjIwMzI4ODY3MTc3NzEy/funny-movie-explanations-1jpg.jpg) rather than a serious attempt to identify a property

Comment: @Valorum couldn't you wait until April 1st was over? I would have closed it then myself.

Comment: @Galastel - No. Because a few minutes after this gets re-opened, some idiot will answer it. And another idiot will upvote their daft answer. Then you won't be able to close it without pestering a moderator.